# Get ItemEventReceiver for whole SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I want to create a SharePoint extension, that needs to get notified for every Item event in the whole SharePoint. Normally, one can use ItemEventReceivers to get such notifications for a specific list. But in order to get the notifications from the whole sharepoint I'd have to add the event receiver for every list in every Web in every Site.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Your question has been answered here already: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37555/how-to-add-event-receivers-to-all-the-lists-in-a-site-collection or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243406/attach-eventreceiver-to-all-lists-of-a-sharepoint-site

Comment: @moontear Thx! I'm trying this out.